# How to specify what kind of is_single post?

Tags: query, sidebar

I have two different kinds of single posts, blog and products, built in the same way with post categories.  The blog has three static categories that the user will use, News, Updates, and Ideas.  This is as far as I've gotten in figuring it out:

```
if (is_single('cat=5')) {
    // show sidebar code for cat=5
} else {
    // show main sidebar code
}
```

Comment: is_singular() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/

Comment: it is not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly do you want to achieve, but if you just want to know the type of your single post, i did post an answer for you.

Comment: @Trikucian, please add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if ( is_singular( 'POST_TYPE' ) )` to determine the type if your singular post.

Remember to change `POST_TYPE` to your desired type.

Answer (score 1):

You want separate single.php or category.php, Create separate template for single single-{post_type}.php and category category-slug.php or category-ID.php